# How to make a crystal report with following view or Postgres crosstab() function?

Tags: database, vb.net, postgresql, crystal-reports, crosstab

I want to make a crystal report from the following view:

[image: view]

I need to make a report with the above view `vConsolPrchOrd` that looks like:

[image: report]

As you can see this is based on the first 3 Rows in my view `vConsolPrchOrd`.

Comment: should i use `crossTab` in `crystal report` ?

Comment: Yes you are correct..cross tab is the best option....use crosstab

Comment: @ypercube there is no `cross post` first you read `questions` in two both site  [here i asked about to making crystal report] [in dba asked about crosstab]

Comment: To me it seems you have (had) one problem to solve. Whether the best is to be solved in Postgres or Crystal reports or with a combined solution, it is still one problem and one question should be asked.

Comment: @ypercube IMO getting responses `Postgres or Crystal reports` is good

Comment: [Cross-posted to dba.SE.](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63893/rows-into-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot i myself found a solution for this, making a `crosstab crystalreport` seems not good to me
so i will explain what i have done is:

*Installed the additional module `tablefunc` which provides the function crosstab(). Since i am PostgreSQL 9.1 i can use `CREATE EXTENSION` for that*

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

and 
converted rows into columns using the following `query`

```
select * from crosstab(' select product,branch,orderqty from vConsolPrchOrd ORDER  by product ',$$values(1::int),(3),(4),(5),(6)$$) as tbl("product" character varying,"1"  numeric,"3" numeric,"4" numeric,"5" numeric,"6" numeric) order by product asc limit 5
```

BEFORE
[image]

AFTER using `crosstab`

[image]

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)